# Getting SerializeObject to use JsonProperty "name" defined inside interface

Tags: json.net

When calling "JsonConvert.SerializeObject" I am passing in an object that implements an interface.  It is the interface that defines the JsonProperty attributes to set the desired JSON object property name.  However when I examine the JSON object that is produced it is using the actual .NET property name, rather than JsonPropertyAttribute value.  This leads me to believe it is only reflecting over the implementation of the interface to find the JsonProperty attributes, rather than the interface itself.  I have verified that if I place the JsonProperty attributes on the implementing class then everything works as expected, but this is not the desired behaviour.  Is there any way to make JSON.NET pick up the JsonPropertyAttributes defined upon the interface as well as (or instead of) the interface.

```
public interface ISpecifyDataPageToGet
{
    [JsonProperty("offset")]
    int PageNumber { get; }

    [JsonProperty("limit")]
    int PageSize { get; }
}

public class PageInfo : ISpecifyDataPageToGet
{
    public PageInfo(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        this.PageNumber = pageNumber;
        this.PageSize = pageSize;
    }

    // I don't want to have to define JsonProperty attribute here
    public int PageNumber { get; private set; }

    // Or here
    public int PageSize { get; private set; }
}

public void MakeCall(ISpecifyDataPageToGet requestMessage)
{
    // I'm passing instance of interface in here, but it still only picks up
    // attributes defined on class implementing interface.
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestMessage, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings());
    ...
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE:** Reported on [Codeplex project site](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/20749)

Comment: I have come across the same behavior, namely:  JsonProperty attributes on the interface are ignored for the object that implements the interface.  It would be nice if the above worked.

Comment: I'm guessing that no one alrady has a fix (the easy way out) If I get chance I'll down load the source and see if it is possible / what would be involved in fixing it / uploading a patch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has now been fixed in the Json.NET codebase by James and is working.
See the [codeplex issue report](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/20749) as well as the [Json.NET 4.0 Release 3 release notes](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2011/10/01/json-net-4-0-release-3-linq-to-json-performance):

> New feature - JsonObject and JsonProperty attributes can now be placed on an interface and used when serializing implementing objects.

Comment: The Link is not working. Could you help provide the working link again?