# How to inherit the attribute from interface to object when serializing it using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, inheritance, json.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
public interface IParent
{
    [JsonProperty]
    int Id {get;set;}
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Parent : IParent
{
    public int Id { get;set; }  
    public string Name {get;set;}   
}

public class Serializer
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        var parent = new Parent() { Id = 1, Name ="Parent"};        
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
                var sw = new StringWriter(sb);

                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                       {
                           NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore                            
                       };

            var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent, Formatting.None, settings);
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

In the above code, the output is **{}**. Is it possible to serialize and get the output as **{"Id":1}**?

Comment: Support for `[JsonProperty]` on interface property declarations has been implemented as of [Json.NET 4.0.3](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2011/10/01/json-net-4-0-release-3-linq-to-json-performance), so now this code just works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/bEIWEF.  As such, this is now a duplicate of [Getting SerializeObject to use JsonProperty “name” defined inside interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5929342/3744182).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is a bad idea.**

Having said that, Newtonsoft provides a way for you to change what's serialized: in this case, you'd subclass [`DefaultContractResolver`](http://json.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/60604#763073) and override `CreateProperty`.

The problem is, it isn't easy to decide when you should opt-in to serialization based on an interface's attributes. For one thing, a class could potentially implement multiple interfaces with conflicting serialization instructions. Moreover, *deserializing* an object into a variable declared as a conflicting interface (for example) won't work. It's fragile and it isn't secure (it allows external code to specify what data an instance reveals).

If you have to do it, the code below works for your case:

```
public class InterfaceContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver, IContractResolver
{
    public InterfaceContractResolver() : this(false) { }
    public InterfaceContractResolver(bool shareCache) : base (shareCache) {}

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        var interfaces = member.DeclaringType.GetInterfaces();
        foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
        {
            foreach (var interfaceProperty in @interface.GetProperties())
            {
                // This is weak: among other things, an implementation 
                // may be deliberately hiding an interface member
                if (interfaceProperty.Name == member.Name && interfaceProperty.MemberType == member.MemberType)
                {
                    if (interfaceProperty.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), true).Any())
                    {
                        property.Ignored = false;
                        return property;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return property;
    }

}
```

Then, when you're creating your serializer, pass it an instance of your resolver in the settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    ContractResolver = new InterfaceContractResolver(true)
};
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I was looking for something similar.

Comment: I am always amazed at Json.NET's flexibility.  It is nice to know that if I ever need to jam to force this into working I can.

Comment: One way of making thousand less volatile would be to make a SerializeAs attribute that forces you to specify only one interface. That or pre-scan for conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929342/getting-serializeobject-to-use-jsonproperty-name-defined-inside-interface)...I do not believe that this works.  JsonProperty attributes on the interface are ignored for the object that implements the interface.

Comment: Thanks for the link frank, I understand that the attributes are not inherited from interfaces to the implementation,as they suffer the Multiple Inheritance issue.

Comment: This answer is out of date, the linked question now has an answer stating that this was implemented in Json.NET 4.0.3.