# Ignore property defined in interface when serializing using JSON.net

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have an interface with a property like this:

```
public interface IFoo {
    // ...

    [JsonIgnore]
    string SecretProperty { get; }

    // ...
}
```

I want the `SecretProperty` to be ignored when serializing all implementing classes. But it seems I have to define the `JsonIgnore` attribute on every implementation of the property. Is there a way to achieve this without having to add the `JsonIgnore` attribute to every implementation? I didn't find any serializer setting which helped me.

Comment: You should add this as an answer and accept it, if it solves your problem.

Comment: I did so now, but I couldn't do it much earlier because I was not allowed to do it less than 8 hours after my question (and because I was not at work at the weekend).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I found this question:

[How to inherit the attribute from interface to object when serializing it using JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951043/how-to-inherit-the-attribute-from-interface-to-object-when-serializing-it-using)

I took the code by Jeff Sternal and added `JsonIgnoreAttribute` detection, so it looks like this:

```
class InterfaceContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public InterfaceContractResolver() : this(false) { }

    public InterfaceContractResolver(bool shareCache) : base(shareCache) { }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        var interfaces = member.DeclaringType.GetInterfaces();
        foreach (var @interface in interfaces)
        {
            foreach (var interfaceProperty in @interface.GetProperties())
            {
                // This is weak: among other things, an implementation 
                // may be deliberately hiding an interface member
                if (interfaceProperty.Name == member.Name && interfaceProperty.MemberType == member.MemberType)
                {
                    if (interfaceProperty.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute), true).Any())
                    {
                        property.Ignored = true;
                        return property;
                    }

                    if (interfaceProperty.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute), true).Any())
                    {
                        property.Ignored = false;
                        return property;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

Using this `InterfaceContractResolver` in my `JsonSerializerSettings`, all properties which have a `JsonIgnoreAttribute` in any interface are ignored, too, even if they have a `JsonPropertyAttribute` (due to the order of the inner `if` blocks).

Answer (score 5):

In more recent versions of Json.NET, applying [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) to interface properties now *just works* and successfully prevents them from being serialized for all implementing types, as long as the property is declared on the same class where the interface is declared.  A custom contract resolver is no longer required.

For instance, if we define the following types:

```
public interface IFoo 
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    string SecretProperty  { get; set; }

    string Include { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo 
{
    public string SecretProperty  { get; set; }
    public string Include { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following test passes in Json.NET 11 and 12 (and probably earlier versions also):

```
var root = new Foo
{
    SecretProperty  = "Ignore Me",
    Include = "Include Me",
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);

Assert.IsTrue(json == "{\"Include\":\"Include Me\"}");// Passes
```

Demo fiddles [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WlagpX) and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DcupZb).

I believe this was added in Json.NET [4.0.3](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/4.0.3) despite the fact that `JsonIgnore` was not mentioned explicitly in the release notes:

> New feature - JsonObject and JsonProperty attributes can now be placed on an interface and used when serializing implementing objects.

(The implementation can be found in [`JsonTypeReflector.GetAttribute<T>(MemberInfo memberInfo)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonTypeReflector.cs#L345).)

However, as [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849613/ignore-property-defined-in-interface-when-serializing-using-json-net/55522993#comment101866867_55522993) by [Vitaly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2595259), this does not work when the property is inherited from a base class of the class where the interface is declared.  Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eliVCu).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Without looking it up, I don't know which version we were using back then (7 years already?!), but we're currently using 11.0.2 in the project in question, so I guess this will go on the todo list for the next refactoring session.

Comment: It doesn't work if property is inherited from base class. Tested with versions 10 and 12. Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eliVCu

Comment: @Vitaly - looks like you're right.  Answer updated.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work when the JsonIgnore is in the interface. That's the problem.

Comment: @madd - can you share a [mcve] for that?  There are two demo fiddles https://dotnetfiddle.net/DcupZb and https://dotnetfiddle.net/WlagpX showing that it works, so it would be helpful to know when it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

I have found it's simplest to create a DTO of only the properties I want and serialize that object to JSON. it creates many small, context specific objects but managing the code base is much easier and I don't have to think about what I'm  serializing vs what I'm ignoring.

Comment: I was looking for a cleverer way to do this, but fear this might end up being the way I do it. :o)

Answer (score -1):

You should add `[DataContract]` in front of the class name.

It changes the default from including all properties, to including only explicitly marked properties. After that, add '[DataMember]' in front of each property you want to include in the JSON output.

Comment: That's absolutely not what I want. I wanted an ignore definition in the interface to be passed up to the top of the class hierarchy so the serializer will ignore my interface property. I do not want the property to be serializable in any implementation of the interface.