# Ignoring implemented interface property for all implementations

Tags: json.net

I've noticed the default JSON serialiser/deserialiser automatically serialises/deserialises all properties, but there's a property of an interface I never want to be serialised/deserialised in all implementations of those interfaces.

Is there a way to take the interface file with an attribute to ensure the property is never serialised or deserialised or is the only approach to add an attribute to all the implementations of the interface or change the interface property to a method?

Comment: Adding `[JsonIgnore]` to the interface property *just works*.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55522993/3744182) to [Ignore property defined in interface when serializing using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8849613/3744182).  In fact I think this is a duplicate, agree?

Comment: Whoops it probably is a duplicate my bad. Thanks for the answer anyway!